# How do I get the last 50 created records in ascending order in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a table that saves executed purchase orders. For a report I want to have the last 50 created purchase orders (the table's ID field is good to identify those) listed in ascending order.

I tried

```
a = Order.limit(50).order("id desc").order("id asc")
```

but that didnt work, neither did

```
a = (Order.limit(50).order("id desc")).order("id asc")
```

nor

```
a = Order.limit(50).order("id desc")")
b = a.order("id asc")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = Order.last(50).reverse
```

The same query as from Mischa's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way is probably to just reverse the result of the query:

```
a = Order.order("id desc").limit(50).reverse
```